# What is the point of a Maven goal?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I come from a Ruby on Rails background and I am learning Java Spring MVC right now. When I try to compile my code using Maven in STS it wants me to include a goal. [All the guides I read on this seem vague and unclear.](https://maven.apache.org/archives/maven-1.x/start/concepts.html) What is the point of a goal? Why can't I just compile my source code and run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand that Maven is **complex** and **modular**.

It does not have any concept of "compiling" your code or "running" your code. What it does is trigger **plugins** in the order of the [build lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Running a Maven goal triggers a particular Maven plugin. For example, running `mvn compile` triggers the [Maven compiler plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/).

This all seems to be overkill for someone just starting in Java, and there are many "why can't Maven just do what its told" questions on SO.

Most of these stem from a fundamental misunderstanding of what Maven *is*. It is not (strictly speaking) designed to "compile and run" your code. It is designed to carry out a number of preconfigured steps in a particular order.

When it comes to "running your code", this gets even trickier:

- to run your code with the maven exec plugin, call `mvn exec:java`. You obviously need to configure the plugin
- to run your code as a webapp with an embedded Tomcat server, call `mvn tomcat7:run-war`.
- to run your code as GWT application in devMode on an embedded webserver call `mvn gwt:run`

What all these goals have in common is that they trigger a **specific**, **pre-configured**, plugin that carries out the task you have asked for.

It is further worth pointing out that Maven is designed to compile, test and *install* your code, not really to *run* it. So whilst may plugins for running code do exist, the real strength of Maven comes from being able to automate the compiling, testing and deployment of code to a Maven repository.

As a final note, the **massive red warning** at the top of the page you linked says:

> Apache Maven 1.x has reached its end of life, and is no longer
>   supported.

Take heed. We're now on [Maven 3.2.X](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.3/release-notes.html). Don't read documentation for ancient and obsolete versions. This will serve no purpose but to confuse you.